# The proof of the Morse index theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I have a question regarding the proof of the Morse index theorem, which asserts that the index of the index form $I$ along a geodesic $\gamma\colon [0,l]\to M$ on a complete manifold is equal to the number of conjugate point $\gamma(t)$ ($t\in(0,l]$), counted with multiplicities.

The proof is roughly like the following (reference likes do Carmo's $\textit{Riemannian Geometry}$). If we let $i(t)$ be the index  and $d(t)$ be the nullity of the index form $I$ on $[0,t]\subseteq[0,l],$ then we have

(1) $i(t-\varepsilon)=i(t)$ for $\varepsilon$ small enough, and

(2) $i(t+ \varepsilon)=i(t)+d(t)$ for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough.

My question is, why will we need (1) to prove the index theorem? Can't we just use (2) above to derive the index theorem?  I mean, it seems (to me) that after we prove $d(t)$ is the multiplicity of the conjugate point $\gamma(t)$ if $d(t)>0,$ (2) then tells us the behavior of $i(t),$ and the result of the theorem. Am I correct?

Any comment is appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that without $(1)$ the function $i$ could admit spontaneous jumps without the nullity contributing. The second point cannot prevent this if $\epsilon > 0$ cannot be chosen independently of $t$.

Comment: It makes sense! Thanks for pointing it out!